# HTML5 Schema and CSS Styling Correct?

Tags: css, html5

I've started my personal website with HTML5.
I would like to get it review to see if I am using the correct schema.

I am looking to get feedback about the structure of HTML5 elements. I think I am overdoing some of the things in the code.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#midcontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#midcontainer::before {
  clear: both;
}

#midcontainer::after {
  clear: both;
}

header {
  background: #ff4242;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header span {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
}

header span.your {
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
  line-height: 30px
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.intro {
  background: #f0f2eb;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 100px 50px;
}

.intro h2 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.intro span {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.intro button {
  background: #f0f2eb;
  border: 2px solid #ff4242;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.intro button:hover {
  background: #ff4242;
  border: 2px solid #ff4242;
  color: #fff;
}

.photography,
.code,
.graphicdesign {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

footer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff4242;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="container">
    <span class="your">YOUR</span><span>NAME</span>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Conact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="intro">
  <h2>Who is this guy? </h2>
  <span>Dude, myth or mega designer!</span>
  <button>get to know me</button>
</div>
<div id="midcontainer">
  <div class="photography">
    <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h3>photography</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="code">
    <i class="fa fa-code fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h3>Code</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="graphicdesign">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
    <h3>Graphic Design</h3>
  </div>
</div>


<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>Designed by <a href="http://uname.com">your name</a></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: This page looks half finished, with missing content, empty `<i>` tags, and a useless `<button>`. What is this page for? Please state the purpose of the code — see [ask].

Comment: @200_success The empty `<i>`s with `fa-*` classes are conventional usage of Font Awesome icons, but +1 to the other points.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically correct, but you might want to look at a few things that have changed with HTML and CSS in the last years:

### Web Fonts

```
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
```

In the bad old days you could only use fonts in web pages that were
already installed on the client system.  Because theses pre-installed fonts
differed from operating system to operating system, a list of similar looking
fonts was specified.  Here "Verdana" was typically found on windows machines, "Geneva" typically on MacOS, an "sans-serif" is a wildcard to finally
use any sans serif font, if none of the named fonts are available.

Since about 2008 browsers can load fonts[see history of web typography](https://prowebtype.com/history/).  Now you can specify exactly
the font you want, and maybe add the wildcard at the end in case anything breaks.
See [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) for free fonts and for the code you need to load them.

So today you would typically write

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

instead of the font list.

### Layout

You use "float" to arrange divs side-by-side.

Since [Spring 2017](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) you can use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/getting-started-css-grid/) instead.

Use it to lay out the whole page on a grid. You will need fewer HTML tags and can forget about "clearfix".

### Responsive Design

The Web has many different output devices.  Even if we just look at
screens, we have big differences in resolution and pixel density.

Your page is geared toward a screen width of 1024px.  On smaller displays parts of your page will only by visibly when scrolling horizontally.  On larger displays you will not use the space available in a meaningful way.

The answer to this is [responsive design](https://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design): start designing your page for a smartphone. Then add different CSS for larger devices using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).